# Troubleshoot JavaScript onchange

Tags: javascript, dom-events, inline

When I use these scripts (inline and external) together only second one works, and first one - not.

First one (inline script) submits the form and loads the list:

```html
<select id="my-select" name="show_user_todo" onchange="document.form_buttons.submit()">
```

Second one sets the color of `select` according to selected option:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  var mySelect = document.getElementById('my-select');

  var setBgColor = function (select) {
    select.style.color = select.options[select.selectedIndex].style.color;
  };

  mySelect.onchange = function () {
    setBgColor(this);
  };
</script>
```

Comment: because here you are not adding eventListeners but just overriding it

Comment: can you show me were? im not javascripter, so its hard to understand.... :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do like this

```
<select id="my-select" name="show_user_todo">

<script type="text/javascript">
    var mySelect = document.getElementById('my-select');

    var setBgColor = function (select) {
      select.style.color = select.options[select.selectedIndex].style.color;
    };

    mySelect.onchange = function () {
      setBgColor(this);
      document.form_buttons.submit();
    };
</script>
```

Comment: Do you know what to do... Now it works, but when select and it refreshes color vanishes... What to do now? :/

Comment: you need to set the color once list is loaded after submit.. so basically set the color in submit function when you are done loading the list

Comment: can you create a fiddle with your code with form submit code also

Comment: @Sidas When you submit a form, the page is reloaded with what the server sends back. If you don't want to reload the page, use AJAX.

Comment: yes.. If `select` is part of `form_buttons` form then you need to use ajax or else you need to send the selected option to the server and send back again to set it selected and set the color accordingly but thats not recommended.

Comment: so how can i use this AJAX in order to keep color and load the info

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004233/jquery-ajax-post-example-with-php#answer-27816373

Comment: How can I configure this with my scripts?

Comment: you need to understand the basic examples, you can find in above comment's url.